# mysql compare consecutive values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a query which joins two tables (users,records) on the user.id which corresponds to the records.user_id

The records table holds multiple rows with a 'type' column that has either 1 or 0 value set.

```
DB::table('users')
        ->join('records_dev.records', function($join) {
            $join->on('users.id', '=', 'records.user_id')
                ->where(...);
        })
        ->get()->toArray();
```

I would like it to return any users which do not have alternate 'type' values but cannot figure out how to perform this logic.

Let's say that the abode return a user array with type values as 0 1 0 this is normal, I would like it to only signal out the users which have 0 0 1, 1 1 0, or so on within their records.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Means you want the users who have alternative 'type' = 0 ??

Comment: just the ones which has multiple entries with a successive double, like first entry 0, second also 0, and a third 1. This as opposed to a regular alternate 0 1 0 rows. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: This is really just an SQL question. Has nothing to do with PHP or Laravel.

Comment: Without an explicit ORDER BY clause there is no "consecutive"

Answer (score 0):

You can join records table twice and on the second join shift the id by 1. Then you can compare if r1.type = r2.type which means that the consecutive rows in type column are the same.

Also, you need to make a custom select in this case.

It should look something like this:

```
DB::table('users')
->select('users.*', 'r1*')
->join('records_dev.records r1', 'users.id', '=', 'r1.user_id')
->join('records_dev.records r2', function ($join) {
    $join->on('r1.user_id', '=', '(r2.user_id - 1)')
        ->where('r1.type', '=', 'r2.type');
})
->get()->toArray();
```

or like this:

```
DB::table('users')
->select('users.*', 'r1*')
->join('records_dev.records r1', 'users.id', '=', 'r1.user_id')
->join('records_dev.records r2', 'r1.user_id', '=', '(r2.user_id - 1)')
->where('r1.type', '=', 'r2.type')
->get()->toArray();
```

This assumes that there is no gap in the user_id column in records table. If there IS a gap then you can add a new column to the records table and sequence it (1, 2, 3, ...). Then use that column instead of user_id like this (if the new column name is seq):

```
$join->on('r1.seq', '=', '(r2.seq - 1)')
```

Comment: can you explain the selected r1 bit please?

Comment: If you mean the `->select('users.*', 'r1*')`, it just means that you do not want to select the columns from r2, because they are the same as r1. It would probably be best to select individual columns as you need them, fe. `->select('users.id', 'users.name', 'users.some_column', 'r1.some_other_column')`.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution where a temporary table is created just for the second 'records' table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporary_records (
       id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (id) ) 
SELECT user_id, id, type 
FROM records ORDER BY user_id ASC, id ASC
```

Then we can find any consecutive entries easily.

```
SELECT user_id FROM (
SELECT  g1.user_id,
        (g1.type LIKE g2.type) AS issue
FROM    temporary_records g1
INNER JOIN  temporary_records g2 ON g2.id = g1.id + 1
WHERE   g1.user_id = g2.user_id ) derived_table WHERE derived_table.issue = 1
```

Is there an easier way? Just asking.